# Spring Boot Jersey Autconfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I want to start a new project using Spring Boot and Jersey. I have read numerous tutorials on how to do this, but one thing still puzzles me. Why do I have to register all my Jersey resources?

As an example, Lokesh Gupta has written a tutorial at https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/#jersey-config where he has the following code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    public JerseyConfig()
    {
        register(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

I don't want to register all my resources this way. Is there a way to get the resources to be picked up by Jersey's resource scanner? Using the method above, will the @Provider annotation of Jersey be honored? Is it possible to set the *jersey.config.server.provider.packages* servlet parameter somewhere?

To sum it all up: "How can I autoconfigure Jersey using Spring Boot?"

Answer (score 2):

If you read in the Spring boot documentation [JAX-RS and Jersey](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey)

> Jersey’s support for scanning executable archives is rather limited.
>   For example, **it cannot scan for endpoints in a package found in a
>   fully executable jar file or in WEB-INF/classes when running an
>   executable war file**. To avoid this limitation, the `packages` method
>   should not be used, and endpoints should be registered individually by
>   using the register method, as shown in the preceding example.

So if you want an executable jar/war file then the answer is no.